# "Халасана не самая сложная асана." Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Знаю, что тире не ставится, если при сказуемом имеется отрицание. Смущает одно: отрицание относится к местоимению, а сам факт, что "Халасана — это асана" не отрицается.

Comment: Точка внутри кавычек? Предложение целиком было необходимо, чтобы показать отсутствие противопоставления.

Answer (score 2):

**ХаласАна  – не самая сложная асана.**

По правилам тире не ставится, если перед сказуемым есть частица НЕ, но это **базовое  правило, которое соблюдается далеко не всегда.**

В данном случае необходимо логически выделить название асаны и разделить паузой/тире группу подлежащего и сказуемого. Если этого не сделать, то предложение прочитать (и понять)  практически невозможно.

Для сравнения рассмотрим пример из Розенталя: **Офицер этот не чЕта вам.** Здесь логически выделено сказуемое (на него падает ударение), пауза не делается, тире не ставится.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

3) если перед сказуемым стоит отрицание не: Офицер этот не чета вам (Фед.); …
Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое: Но объяснение — не оправдание (М. Г.);